# The getter 'physicalSize' isn't defined for the type 'PlatformDispatcher'

Tags: flutter, dart

After the latest Flutter upgrade to 3.10.0 the window api is depreciated and i am trying to use View.of(context).platformdispatcher instead, how should i replace window.viewPadding to View.of(context).platformdispatcher.viewPadding since it throws me this

`The getter 'viewPadding' isn't defined for the type 'PlatformDispatcher'. Try importing the library that defines 'viewPadding', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'viewPadding'.dar`

The ViewPadding getter should be there for PlatformDispatcher as well

Answer (score 0):

[viewPadding](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FlutterView/viewPadding.html) is defined in [FlutterView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FlutterView-class.html). To get the `FlutterView` you can use:

```dart
final views = PlatformDispatcher.instance.views;
```

The [views](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/PlatformDispatcher/views.html) returns a Iterable of `FlutterViews`. You can then access the first view to get the `viewPadding`:

```dart
final viewPadding = PlatformDispatcher.instance.views.first.viewPadding;
```